# HTML Tables equal column height

Tags: html, css

Hi im a beginner in css i have these table below its 3 separate table and i would like to make all of the table column height equal is there any easy method to go about this? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated thank you!

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nigelchuan/10t4gv92/6/)

```
<body>
        <div class="center">
            <table class="fruitsTable class">
                <thead>
                    <th>Fruits</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Apples</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Grapes</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Oranges</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mango</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Papaya</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Banana</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Kiwi</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="fruitsTable2 class" >
                <thead>
                    <th>Fruits</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mango</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Papaya</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Banana</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Kiwi</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of equal heights? There is not enough content in the second and third tables to fill the space so...?

Comment: @wazz Yes that's the problem i want the column to be same height even though there's not enough content in the tables just to make it more presentable.

Comment: Maybe the idea isn't to make the tables the same height but to have borders that go from top to bottom? Maybe wrap each table in a div and work on those heights? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

***it's possible when a table change by CSS, but it's not good,***

**You can try this code here https://jsfiddle.net/10t4gv92/21/** Or

```css
.fontcolor {
  color: #25BAD0;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}
table,
table tr,
table tr td,
table tr th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;

  border:1px solid #25BAD0;
}

table tr,
table th,
table tr td,
table tbody,
table thead {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  width:100%;
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #25BAD0;
}

td {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.fruitsTable th { width:100%; }
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <table class="fruitsTable class">
    <thead>
      <th>Fruits</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Apples</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Grapes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mango</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Papaya</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mango</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Papaya</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Banana</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kiwi</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="fruitsTable2 class">
    <thead>
      <th>Fruits</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mango</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Papaya</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Banana</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kiwi</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="fruitsTable3 class">
    <thead>
      <th>Fruits</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Banana</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kiwi</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Banana</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kiwi</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Banana</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kiwi</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way to keep the original design?

Comment: I do not know if there is any other way, i am just trying primary solve your problem.